# allow snap apps to access data from outside of container

Tags: unity, permissions, libreoffice, evolution, snap

I installed libreoffice from snap. The program works fine but I'm locked in the snap container. 
Trying to open an office attachment in Evolution results in:

> Access to
>   /home/user/.cache/evolution/tmp/evolution-user/Document.xlsx
>   was denied.

I get the idea that snap packages are self contained and secure, but in order to work within a system other packages that were installed from .deb should be granted access to snap. How can I do this without compromising security?

**Update:** In response to user spktkpkt, when I list

```
$snap interfaces

Slot                     Plug
:bluetooth-control       -
...
:gsettings               emacs-tealeg
:hardware-observe        canonical-livepatch
:home                    emacs-tealeg,libreoffice
```

I can see that libreoffice is connected to :home but, maybe because my document is in a hidden folder (.cache) it can't be accessed.

Note that home interface can only access non-hidden files as described on the [interfaces reference](http://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/interfaces) page of snap:

> [home Interface] Can access non-hidden files in user's $HOME and gvfs mounted directories owned by the user to read/write/lock.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it yet, but there should be a interface to communicate with the $HOME directory. [Here](http://snapcraft.io/docs/core/interfaces) is some information about interfaces and [here](http://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/interfaces) is a list with all available interfaces.

Comment: Seems to be the way, but I guess the hidden file causes some issues?

Comment: In theory there is the personal-files interface (https://docs.snapcraft.io/the-personal-files-interface/9357). But 1. that is not available for LibreOffice and 2. that would open up all .config files as well and may weaken the security snaps provide.